# What means Workers = List[str]? How to add string?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I tried to add string value to this list but it called error:
*builtins.TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'*

```
from typing import List
Workers = List[str]
Workers.append("aaa")
```

Can I ask what it is I no list and how to add string here?

Thank you

Comment: Just use `workers = []` (variables should be lowercase by convention) to make a list. `List[str]` is a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), not a real Python list.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here is creating a type alias, not a list. You can read about type aliases [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases). You can simply make a list and append whatever you would like to it as such:

```
workers = []
workers.append("worker1")
```

However, what it looks like what you are trying to do is denote or "hint" what types the elements within the list should be. You can do so by creating a type alias as you did in your original code, and use that type alias to hint to your interpreter or Lint what should be there.

```
from typing import List

Workers = List[str]
lst_of_workers: Workers = []

lst_of_workers.append("worker1")
```

This is with the type hint as List[str]
[image: type hint is str]
This is with the type hint as List[int]
[image: type hint is int]
Notice how my interpreter lets me know I should use a string when its type hinted as such, and integer when it is the other way.

Comment: I think what the OP intended is to create a new list and type-hint it as a list of strings. Maybe you can [edit] your answer and improve 
it by also showing them how to do that